# Reload d3.js graph on node click

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I've had a d3 graph with a bunch of nodes based off items. When I click on one of those nodes, the graph is reloaded with data based off the clicked node.

I use a URL structure like so:
http://siteurl.com/index.html?item=

When a node is clicked, I have a function that runs the `d3.json(` function again with the new URL and then executes the update function again.

I've recently changed my code so that the node word appears below the node. <strike>Now I get an 'undefined is not a function' error on the line of code with `node.exit().remove();`</strike>
*EDIT: Issue fixed from @Elijah's answer, but does not resolve my issue.*

So when I click on a node, links get removed, then regenerated, but the nodes from the previous graph remain.

[image]

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tn5yb32t/)

Here's some of my JS

```
$wordToSearch = "bitter";

var w = 960,
    h = 960,
    node,
    link,
    root,
    title;

var jsonURL = 'http://desolate-taiga-6759.herokuapp.com/word/' + $wordToSearch;

d3.json(jsonURL, function(json) {
    root = json.words[0]; //set root node
    root.fixed = true;
    root.x = w / 2;
    root.y = h / 2 - 80;
    update();
});

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .on("tick", tick)
    .charge(-700)
    .gravity(0.1)
    .friction(0.9)
    .linkDistance(50)
    .size([w, h]);

var svg = d3.select(".graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);



//Update the graph
function update() {
    var nodes = flatten(root),
    links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

    // Restart the force layout.
    force
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .start();

    // Update the links…
    link = svg.selectAll("line.link")
        .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

    // Enter any new links.
    link.enter().insert("svg:line", ".node")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    // Exit any old links.
    link.exit().remove();

    // Update the nodes…
    node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .call(force.drag);

    node.append("circle")   
        .attr("r", 10)
        .on("click", click)
        .style("fill", "red");

    node.append("text")
        .attr("dy", 10 + 15)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.word });

    svg.selectAll(".node").data(nodes).exit().remove();

}

function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}




/***********************
*** CUSTOM FUNCTIONS ***
***********************/

//Request extended JSON objects when clicking a clickable node
function click(d) {
    $wordClicked = d.word;

    var jsonURL = 'http://desolate-taiga-6759.herokuapp.com/word/' + $wordClicked;
    console.log(jsonURL);

    updateGraph(jsonURL);
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [], i = 0;

    function recurse(node) {
        if (node.children) node.size = node.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + recurse(v); }, 0);
        if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
        nodes.push(node);
        return node.size;
    }

    root.size = recurse(root);
    return nodes;

}

//Update graph with new extended JSON objects
function updateGraph(newURL) {
    d3.json(newURL, function(json) {
        root = json.words[0]; //set root node
        root.fixed = true;
        root.x = w / 2;
        root.y = h / 2 - 80;

        update();
    });
}

function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)  {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas why thats not working please?

EDIT: Updated my JS based from @Elijah's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the 3 states enter, exit and update, separate from each other:

```
node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes);  // base data selection, this is the update

var nodeE = node
    .enter();  // handle the enter case

var nodeG = nodeE.append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);  // add group ON ENTER

nodeG.append("circle")  
    .attr("r", 10)
    .on("click", click)
    .style("fill", "red");  // append circle to group ON ENTER

nodeG.append("text")
    .attr("dy", 10 + 15)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d.word }); // append text to group ON ENTER

node.exit().remove();  // handle exit
```

Update fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tn5yb32t/1).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that here:

`node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .call(force.drag);`

You're defining `node` as `svg.selectAll(".node").enter()` which means your variable now refers to the selection enter behavior and not the selection itself. So when you try to change exit behavior on it with: `node.exit().remove();`

..you're trying to access the `.exit()` behavior not of the selection but of the selection's `.enter()` behavior. Replace that with:

`svg.selectAll(".node").data(nodes).exit().remove();`

And that should fix your problem. There may be something else going on, but that's definitely going to cause issues.

Edited to add:

You should also update your tick function so that it doesn't reference `node` which is now assigned to the `#selection.enter()` and not the selection and instead reference the selection:
`svg.selectAll("g.node")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });`

Comment: You're not wrong, that was definitely causing an issue. But unfortunately it didn't solve my issue. I've created a fiddle to demonstrate my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/tn5yb32t/

Comment: Your tick function is also referencing the `node` variable, which because it's assigned to the enter() behavior isn't updating to deal with the newly created nodes.

Comment: @OliverEvans, to elijah's point, here's a fiddle with cleaned up enter/exit/update selections:  http://jsfiddle.net/tn5yb32t/1/, it works now.